# Why does CLR use a two-pass exception model?

Tags: c#, exception, clr

There's a chapter in C# in Depth, 4th Edition concerning exception filters added in C# 6. It describes the CLR's exception handling model:

> You’re probably used to the idea of the CLR unwinding the stack as an exception “bubbles up” until it’s caught. What’s more surprising is exactly how this happens. The process is more complicated than you may expect using a two-pass model. This model uses the following steps:
>
> - The exception is thrown, and the *first pass* starts.
> - The CLR walks down the stack, trying to find which catch block will handle the exception. (We’ll call this the *handling catch block* as shorthand, but that’s not official terminology.)
> - Only catch blocks with compatible exception types are considered.
> - If a catch block has an exception filter, the filter is executed; if the filter returns false, this catch block *won’t* handle the exception.
> - A catch block without an exception filter is equivalent to one with an exception filter that returns true.
> - Now that the handling catch block has been determined, the *second pass* starts:
> - The CLR unwinds the stack from the point at which the exception was thrown as far as the catch block that has been determined.
> - Any finally blocks encountered while unwinding the stack are executed. (This doesn’t include any finally block associated with the handling catch block.)
> - The handling catch block is executed.
> - The finally statement associated with the handling catch block is executed, if there is one.

From the perspective of a C# developer, the only difference between two-pass semantics as opposed to a single pass that handles everything seems to be the ordering of exception filters vs `finally` blocks execution - in two-pass semantics all filters are evaluated before any `finally` block does. The more I think about it the less I can see why it was decided that way.

1. Doing a single pass sounds more efficient, so I'd assume this would be the default implementation to choose unless there's sufficient reason to pick another.
2. Executing `finally` clauses after the handling block has been chosen may cause the control-flow to enter a block after the filtering predicate has been invalidated. A simple example showing this:

```cs
public class C
{
    private static int State = 42;

    public static void Foo()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        finally
        {
            State = 17;
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            Foo();
        }
        catch (Exception) when (State == 42)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(State);
        }
    }
}
```

```
> 17
```

This is counterintuitive, as when writing code for the `catch` block it's easy to read this code as "when I enter the `catch` block `State` is always `42`", while the actual semantics are "when I enter the `catch` block I know that *when the caught exception was thrown the `State` was `42`*". So the literal reading of the line does not work - it's *not* "`catch` `Exception` `when` `State` equals `42`", it's "`catch` `Exception` if `when` it was thrown `State` equaled `42`".

3. You can "reverse" that and craft a `finally` block that will make a lower filter applicable. So if we modify the code from point 2. to have `when (State == 17)`, the exception will not be caught and will crash the application, even though intuitively one would think it "passes" the `catch` block `when` `State` equals `17`.
4. One advantage of this model is that all `finally` blocks are independent from filtering predicates. So if the filters had any side-effects we have a guarantee they will be run sequentially bottom-up before any `finally` blocks are ran. But this is arguable, as filters with side-effects seem like an abuse of the system, while `finally` blocks are ordinary code that usually *needs* to exert some kind of a side effect to clean up.

Listing all of the above leads me to think that either:

- I don't see some benefit that this model has over the "easier" one-pass model; or
- there is a deep, technical reason that has to do with low-level stuff and that's why CLR just *has* to be this way in order to work.

I'd like to know which one it is, and if it's a deep, technical reason please give me a "for dummies" rundown on it. Jon Skeet states in that chapter that "[the origin of this model] is deeper into the CLR than I like to venture", so I expect the reason to be technical and non-obvious, but it'd be nice hearing a reasoning from someone who's an expert in the CLR infrastructure.

Comment: Behavior is dictated by the CLI specification, Ecma-335.  It is normally pretty good at giving rationale, but it is silent about this one.  There are multiple plausible theories, my personal favorite is consistency.  Finally blocks can wreak a lot of havoc.  Not that much they could do to isolate filters, other than leaving the feature out of the C# language as long as they could.

Comment: @HansPassant: In many cases, the proper semantics for a function should be to process cleanup differently in the "normal termination" and "exception" cases, but functions making such a distinction should not impose an obstacle to first-pass exception handling.  Using filters to make such a distinction is ugly, but I'm unaware of any better language construct.  I dislike the idea that language people targeting a particular environment should impose their own preferred abstraction model over that of the actual target, especially if the target is supposed to support multi-language programming.

Comment: Thanks for edit @V0ldek.  Votes retracted :)

Comment: Lets say that something changed the value of State to 5 before the exception was thrown, then the exception would be unhanded, but it can't know this until after the filter is executed. The two pass system allows the filter to be executed and the exception identified as unhandled before any unwinding takes place and so the debugger (or memory dump) can provide a more useful experience. In the one pass system, the Foo method is unwound (the value of State changed to 17 and locals/parameters lost) before the filter is executed and debugger realizes that it will be unhandled.

Answer (score 1):

Although the tooling isn't set up to exploit all of the potential advantages of the two-passed design, there are many situations where code at the spot where an exception occurs won't have any immediate way of knowing whether it would be useful to examine within the debugger, or otherwise log, aspects of the system state that would be "cleaned up" before execution reaches the exception handler.

If a function to e.g. read some data from a remote web site is invoked in some contexts where code is expecting that it might fail (and would catch an exception), and in some contexts where failure would be unexpected, it may be useful to be able to suspect execution to examine the state of the socket if an exception is thrown in the latter scenarios, without having to suspend execution in cases where the failure is anticipated.

Note that this design only works if functions avoid catching exceptions that they're not going to resolve.  Unfortunately, languages make it difficult to handle normal and failure-related cleanup differently without catching exceptions they have no intention of resolving, and thus giving whatever throws the exception no way of determining, prior to performing their cleanup, whether the exceptions will be resolved.